# PHP delete files with filename lower than pattern

Tags: php, timestamp, delete-file

I need to delete files with name of a UNIX timestamp having a lower number than a timestamp specified.

I heard something about `glob()` but I'm not sure how to use it in this case.
Best would be putting file names in array to use loop to remove them.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
Why so much downvotes?

Comment: yes **unlink()** is what you use

Comment: @donald123 Yes I know, but how to delete files with filename lower than specified number

Comment: You haven't stated a question. You didn't bother to TRY anything or even read the manual (php.net will tell you all about `glob()`). And your statement is incoherent. gather your thoughts and try again.

Comment: @ARBY I've looked to `find` function in bash but I have no idea how to do it

Comment: Why so much downvotes?

Comment: @rghome it is PHP but somebody added tag bash

Comment: @David8: Please read through the [ask] and [help] pages to get a better feel for why you're gathering downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. This assumes your files are .txt files and that you want to delete anything with a filename earlier than the current time. These are things you should have specified in your question.

```
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    $fn = rtrim($filename,".txt");
    if(is_numeric($fn) && $fn < time()) unlink($filename);
}
```

Comment: @Adelphia: Asking for upvotes and accepted answers is generally against [so]'s user etiquette guidelines, as discussed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297597/74757).